# How to make a date formula which calculates booking date + current month + 3 months(90 days) in salesforce

Tags: formula, date

**Example:**

> If Booking date is -> 7 June 2017, I want the formula to calculate the
>   current month (June) + 3 months(90 days), and the formula should
>   return 29th September 2017

**Calculating as follows:**

> June + 90 days [31 days in July + 31 days in August + 28 days in
>   September].

This formula is to be used in a process builder to set a expiry date.

Comment: I didn't get your example. If you 7 June 2017 +90 days = 5 September 2017, but not 29th September 2017 as you showed in example. Can you post one more example

Comment: So as today is 7th June, I want to retain entire June and counting of 90 days must start from July.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following formula to calculate desired date:

```
    IF(
        MONTH(BookingDate__c) == 12,
        DATE( 
            YEAR(BookingDate__c) +1, 
            1, 
            1
        ),
        DATE( 
            YEAR(BookingDate__c), 
            MONTH(BookingDate__c)+1, 
            1
        )
    )+90
```

Comment: Is there a way I could make these as full  months? Example: Instead of exact 90 days from July, I would want it to be 3 full months from July. And the expiry date must be - 30th Sept 2017 (Last day of the month)

Comment: @Cheryl yes, I've answered  on it [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178412/how-to-make-a-date-formula-which-calculates-current-month-3-full-months-in-sal/178418#178418)