# How to make a date formula which calculates current month + 3 Full months in Salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am using a Process builder to set value to the  field expiry_date__c based on booking_date__c

Example 1:

If booking_date__c is 12th June 2017, the expiry_date__c must be calculated as current month + 3 full months from July. So expiry date must get populated to 30th September.

Example 2:
If booking_date__c is 5th February 2017, expiry_date__c must be 31st May 2017

Comment: expiry_date__c  is a formula field of just date field ?

Comment: Try with this logic. DATE(YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate)+3,1)-1

Comment: Think it should be DATE(YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate)+4,1)-1. if you have 3 it goes to May but cheryl wants it to be end of the 3rd month.

Comment: @ShravanBoddula your formula is not working, when month is October or further months

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria - the 'expiry_date__c' is a date field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formula should consider two cases, when month <= 8 and month > 8.
The following formula works for any date.

```
IF(
    MONTH(Date__c) <= 8,
    DATE(
        YEAR(Date__c),
        MONTH(Date__c)+4,
        1)
    -1
    ,
    DATE(
        YEAR(Date__c)+1,
        MONTH(Date__c)+4-12,
        1)
    -1
)
```

Comment: That works perfect @Alexander, thank you. So I see the catch was to split them in two different cases.